# Como hacer un insert en mysql usando if y select?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Hola amigos tengo un pequeño problema intentando un insert en mysql con if y select, el problema es que la base de datos donde trabajo usa diminutivos para guardar la información pero al momento de guardar los datos a traves del programa que usan allí tiene que aparecer la información sin diminutivos, ejemplo en la base aparece en el estado civil de un paciente "ca" que es casado o "so" que es soltero, en el programa aparece Casado o Soltero, no "ca" ni "so", he estado intentando usar este código pero nada:

```sql
insert into datosdonante select if(edocivil='Casado','ca', if(edocivil= 'Soltero','so','') As edocivil;
```

Algunos de ustedes han hecho un insert como ese?

Comment: Hablamos de un INSERT, por tanto de una fila nueva, no tienes contra qué comparar, lo propio aquí sería hacer un reemplazo de cada cadena antes de insertarla (asumiendo que esos datos vienen de alguna parte, lo cual no explicas por cierto).

Answer (score 1):

Con el poco contexto que das, solo puedo imaginar como posible solución el uso del `CASE`, por ejemplo:

```
INSERT INTO datosdonante 
SELECT 
CASE 
 WHEN edocivil= 'Casado' then 'ca'
 WHEN edocivil= 'Soltero' then 'so'
 ELSE ''
END  As edocivil....;
```

Intenta ajustarlo a tu caso real

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió!!!